# How to run script on a continuous loop

Tags: linux, bash

I am not understanding how to run this script continuously.  It is used to check if the size of `/var/spool/mail` gets larger, and will show an output of "You have mail".

I can get it to run, I just don't know how to make it run without stopping.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=/var/spool/mail/will
filesize="$(du -b "$filename")"
filesizeold="${filesize//[!0-9]/}"
echo $filesizeold
sleep 10;
filename=/var/spool/mail/will
filesize="$(du -b "$filename")"
filesizenew="${filesize//[!0-9]/}"
echo $filesizenew
for (( ;; ))  
do
if [ $filesizeold -ne $filesizenew ];
then
break
fi
done
echo "$USER, You have mail"
```

Comment: Research [Bash Loops](http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-loops.php) -- to me it looks like you're attempting to use `for` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the terminal window your script will stop after a timeout. With nohup .. & your script will run until it is ready.
This should do the trick;

```
nohup yourscript.sh &
```

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: While this may be the answer they are looking for, its good practice to provide a bit more detail to what you posted for other readers.  Also, try to blockquote the important bits of the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you enter the loop, the two file sizes don't change so either you exit the loop immediately, or you loop indefinitely. Your code should be more like (warning: untested):

```
filename=/var/spool/mail/$USER
filesizeold=$(du -b "$filename")
echo "Filesizeold: $filesizeold"
while true
do
    filesizenew=$(du -b "$filename")
    echo "Filesizenew: $filesizenew"
    if [ $filesizeold -ne $filesizenew ];
    then
        break
    fi
    echo "Still same size, sleeping and looping"
    sleep 10
done
echo "$USER, You have mail"
```

(replaced your `for` by a more usual `while` but that wasn't the problem)